# Running spring boot in google-cloud-eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I've raised [an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2154#issuecomment-315759631) in Google-cloud-eclipse but the situation is as follows.

I can run a spring-boot application in google appengine standard using the java8 profile, to do this however requires removing the embedded tomcat engine.

If I add a SpringBootServletInitializer then the project never shows as started in eclipse. (despite having started).

Is there a convenient flow for developing against Google app engine including spring boot, that allows for code changes on the fly?

[Issue raised against google-cloud-eclipse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2154#issuecomment-315759631)

Comment: I've a minimal working example at https://github.com/Athas1980/j8-spring-gce-standard-hook I don't know why that project works though so it doesn't really answer the question. Though I guess it partially answer it. Mor info in the issue linked in the question.

Comment: The issue was thats linked was due to spring redirecting JUL logging.